# Alternatives to CDSs for default term structure?

Tags: cds, default, default-probability

The CDS market seems to be drying up, funding&liquidity issues are now prevalent over credit, so other sources for default probabilities are needed.

What else is commonly used to obtain a default term structure? ASW spreads/credit OAS? ASW + early termination + repo?

Comment: am I the only one who does not understand the title ? ;)

Comment: Thanks, probably an edit gone wrong...  (we can delete these comments anyway.)